# RStudio tells me packages required in a .r file are not installed - but I've been using them for years! What gives?

Tags: r, rstudio

I've been using RStudio for a long while now (not that I'm any good at it). Over the course of the years I've installed many packages for use in my work, from the mega-popular (e.g. `tidyverse`) to the very niche.

I wake up this morning and get into RStudio, where the three `.r` files I've been working on for different projects are open. At the top of each of them, it tells me with a little yellow warning triangle that packages _____ are "required but not installed". It says that for every package I've specified in each `.r` file with `library()`.

I'm not sure what to do to fix this. When I search my hard drive for the names of packages, they still show up: sure enough, `tidyverse` still occupies the directory **"~\R\win-library\3.5\tidyverse"**, for example. I've attempted restarting the `R` session a number of times, too, with no luck. I feel like this is some very obvious oversight on my part but I can't see what it is. I've also done a few searches of StackOverflow to see if anyone's had this happen before - I can't be the first - but I haven't found anything. If I've missed it, I apologize. Also, I'm running

What is RStudio not "seeing" here that it saw before?

tl;dr - `RStudio` is telling me that I don't have packages I've used for years, as recently as yesterday. What's happening here?

Comment: Check `.libPaths()`. Something changed your configuration. Also possibly related: did you recently update R?

Comment: Hello Konrad, thanks for the quick reply. I haven't recently updated R, no, but I'll check `.libPaths()`. To troubleshoot the issue, I allowed the error message to "reinstall" `dplyr` to see what might happen. A search of my hard drive now reveals two `dplyr` folders, one with "Date modified" today, April 19 2020, and the other on March 9 2020. I presume this second one is the "original" one, which R isn't seeing.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Here it is: `> .libPaths()
[1] "C:/Users/dude/R/win-library/3.5"    "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.5.1/library"`

Comment: You may wish to take this time and update to the latest version of R (v 3.6.3) and then reinstall the needed packages.